# Count array & in_array in one function

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a better/shorter way to perform the following:

```
$stock_array = array("soccer" => "0");
if (count($stock_array) == 1 && in_array('0', $stock_array)) {...}
```

I want to check if the array has 1 element, and the value is 0.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your demand?

Comment: `if isset($stock_array['soccer']) && empty($stock_array['soccer'])` I guess

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Given your example the condition will always evaluate to `TRUE`, so you can omit the `if` completely :-)

Comment: @JiriHrazdil That was an example I guess.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: I know - but the example should demonstrate what is wanted by the OP. And this example fails to do that.

Comment: only `if (in_array('0', $stock_array)) {` also good in your case.

Comment: I thought maybe there is a pre-function like empty() ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your title, this provides if the count is one and its value is 0

```
$count = array_count_values($stock_array);
if ($count == array('0' => 1)) {
  //something
}
```

Or you can also use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with `empty()`, if you are looking for a pre-function kind of answer: This will return True if all the values in the array are empty or `0`.

```
if (empty(array_filter($stock_array))) {
  //something
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much jitendrapurohit. Ik works for me. Ik believe my title was not clear enough. My appologize to everyone.

I could also use: if (array_sum($stock_array)==0) {''}

Comment: Both solutions imply creation of a temporary array. Although the expressions may look simple in writing, they are not as efficient as `count` and `current`, or even `array_sum`.

Comment: @SaraZ, how about `array ('a' => 0, 'b' => 0)`? Both `array_sum` and the last version in the answer will return `true`, while the count is 2. If you want to check for the count, you _have to_ to call `count()`.

Comment: No problem. All what I want is to check if the count is not 0. If Zero then show nothing.
I apologize for not being clear with my question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can try using the following code.

```
if (array_search('0', array_values($stock_array)) == 0) {...}
```

But this doesn't tell if the array has only this element.

From your question, I can understand you are trying to do:

- Check the length of array to be `1`.
- Check if the value exists in the array.

The solution I provided, checks if that's the first value of the array. But to check the length of array, you need to have another as well.

Comment: Thanks. But I have to check if the array has 1 element